# read/write unicode data in MySql

Tags: c#, sql, mysql, unicode

I am using MySql DB and want to be able to read & write unicode data values. For example, French/Greek/Hebrew values.

My client program is C# (.NET framework 3.5).

How do i configure my DB to allow unicode? and how do I use C# to read/write values as unicode from MySql?

### Upddate: 7 Sep. 09

OK, So my Schema, Table & columns are set to 'utf8' + collation 'utf8_general_ci'. I run the 'set names utf8' when the connection is opened. so far so good... but, still values are saved as '??????? '

any ideas?

### The Solution!

OK, so for C# client to read & write unicode values, you must include in the **connection string**: charset=utf8

for example: server=my_sql_server;user id=my_user;password=my_password;database=some_db123;charset=utf8;

of course you should also define the relevant table as utf8 + collation utf8_bin.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The Solution!

OK, so for C# client to read & write unicode values, you must include in the connection string: charset=utf8

for example: server=my_sql_server;user id=my_user;password=my_password;database=some_db123;charset=utf8;

of course you should also define the relevant table as utf8 + collation utf8_bin.

Comment: Thanks, I got this issue too and your anwser helped :).

Comment: Just as extra
SCHEMA/DATABASE creation : CREATE SCHEMA your_database CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the collation for your MySQL schema, tables or even columns.

Most of the time, the `utf8_general_ci` collation is used because it is case insensitive and accent insensitive comparisons.

On the other hand, `utf8_unicode_ci` is case sensitive and uses more advanced sorting technics (like sorting eszet ('ß') near 'ss'). This collation is a tiny bit slower than the other two.

Finally, `utf8_bin` compares string using their binary value. Thus, it also is case sensitive.

If you're using MySQL's [Connector/NET](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.0.html) (which I recommend), everything should go smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this query before any other fetch or send:

```
SET NAMES UTF8
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the db charset to UTF-8 (if you are using utf-8), collation for relevant tables/fields to utf, execute SET NAMES 'UTF-8' before doing queries, and of course make sure you set the proper encoding in the html that is showing the output.

Comment: for collation i have several values to select, like: utf_bin, utf8_general_ci, utf8_unicode_ci, etc. What is the preferred?

Comment: also, can you give an SQL query example for INSERT & SELECT using the "SET NAMES" ?

Comment: Collation tells MySQL the rules for sorting the data alphabetically , if you are looking to support a specific language check if there is a specific ruleset, otherwise use one of the general ones.

You only need to run SET NAMES once per established connection.