# Inserting diacritic characters into MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, diacritics

I have MySQL database with table *MySqlTable* which is encoded utf8_slovak_ci and I'd like to INSERT strings with diacritics chars(ľščťžýáí...) typical for slovak language via C# code.

I'm using MySql.Data.MySqlClient namespace for allowing MySql objects.
My C# method:

```
    public void Insert(string sqlQuery, params string[] strings) 
    {
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection);

        for (int i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++)
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@str" + i, strings[i]));
        }

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Chyba!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
        finally 
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Calling this method from program:

```
database.Insert(query, newEmployee.Name);
```

where query is

```
string query = @"INSERT INTO MySqlTable(name) " +
                        "VALUES(@str0)";
```

Where is the problem...
When I try to insert some string icluding that special characters (f.e. *Anča*), it is saved like *Anca* in the database. But when I execute corresponding INSERT query via phpmyadmin, it is saved properly. Problem chars are just *ľčťďň* (saved like *lctdn*), other chars like *šžýáíéúäô* are saved OK.
Anybody knows where could be a problem? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the connection string specify "charset=utf8;". For example: 
"Datasource=192.168.48.128;Database=something;uid=user;pwd=password;charset=utf8;"

And of course set the charset of the table to utf-8 and the collation to the slovak variant.

Worked for hungarian language.

Credits: [read/write unicode data in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385994/read-write-unicode-data-in-mysql)

Comment: Man! I've been waiting for this answer for over 2 months. Thanx, it's working perfectly. I'm sorry that I didn't notice that answer you linked here.

Answer (score 2):

Equivalent for mysql command line tools is **--default-character-set** parameter. For example:

```
mysql -h host -u user -ppass --default-character-set=utf8
mysql> source make_db.sql
```

where make_db.sql is sql script in utf (with diacritics).