# Save in mysql line that is in greek letter C#

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, grammar

Greek characters in database are like question marks("?????"). I can't find a solution. when I insert Greek letters in MySQL are like question marks. Tha collation in the talbe in mysql is utf8.

What i am doing wrong?

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {


            int col = this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
            int row = this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;




         if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["priceoneDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Index)
                  {
                     string name =  dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col - 1].Value.ToString();

                        string pric= dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value.ToString();

//in this row i am getting the line ok
                     MessageBox.Show(name); 


                      MessageBox.Show(pric);

                      lawyerspriceDataSet ds = new lawyerspriceDataSet();
                      lawyerspriceDataSetTableAdapters.reportTableAdapter daReport = new lawyerspriceDataSetTableAdapters.reportTableAdapter();
                      daReport.Fill(ds.report);
                      try
                      {
                          daReport.Insert(name, pric); //i save the info in the table


                      }

                      catch (Exception ex)
                      {
                          MessageBox.Show("error");
                      }


           }
   ![enter image description here][1]
```

[image]

Comment: A solution to your problem is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385994/read-write-unicode-data-in-mysql

Comment: i cant find the place in my code to put charset=utf8

Comment: You should add it to the connection string. It is probably located in the app.config file of your winforms application.

Comment: server=kosh-PC;User Id=root;database=lawyersprice;Persist Security Info=True;Character Set=utf8 .  i have make it but still doesnt work

Comment: Did you try CharSet=utf8?

Comment: You was right! i go to my "nameofapp">settings and i put the string charset=utf8 , and then i went on my database table and i put collation to utf8_bin and worked. So if you want put it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer help me to fix it **[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385994/read-write-unicode-data-in-mysql)**

I go to my "nameofapp">settings and i put the string charset=utf8 , and then i went on my database table and i put collation to utf8_bin and worked