# Storing Marathi (Indian Language) data in MySQL database using VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, character-encoding

I'm using VB.net and MySQL for my project

I want to store Marathi text in the MySQL database, I googled for hours and found a half of a solution by changing the MySQL database encoding to utf-8. I can manually (through PHPMyAdmin)store Marathi characters in Mysql database.

But, when I try to insert some text using VB.net, I get "???"(Question marks) instead of Marathi characters.

Do I need to set encoding in VB.Net also? 
If so then how?

Here's the code to insert data in the database

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    Try
        Dim sql As String
        sql = "Insert into info(taluka,village,yojana,group_name," + _ 
            "reg_no,president_name,mobile,crop," + _ 
            "evaluation,amount,characteristic) values('" & _
            cmbTaluka.SelectedItem.ToString & "','" & _
            cmbVillage.SelectedItem.ToString & "','" & _
            cmbYojana.SelectedItem.ToString & "','" & _
            txtGroup.Text & "','" & txtReg.Text & "','" & _
            txtPresident.Text & "','" & txtMobile.Text& "','" & _
            cmbCrop.SelectedItem.ToString & "','" & _
            cmbYear.SelectedItem.ToString + _
            cmbType.SelectedItem.ToString & "','" & _
            Val(txtAmount.Text) & "','" & txtChar.Text & "')"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try
End Sub
```

And here's the table :
[image: Marathi Characters]
the first row was manually inserted through PHPMyAdmin

the second was using above code.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to populate the query and how it's being executed against the database?

Comment: just added the code in the question to insert the data into database

Comment: so for instance is `txtGroup` a normal TextBox control?  Also be aware that this code is vunerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385994/read-write-unicode-data-in-mysql) is probably related, if not a duplicate - try adding "charset=utf8" to your connection string.

Comment: @JamesThorpe, thank you friend.. adding "charset=utf8" solved the problem.. Thank you so much.. and I will fix the code to prevent sql injection.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

utf8 needs to be established in about 4 places.

- The column(s) in the database -- Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to verify that they are explicitly set to utf8, or defaulted from the table definition.  (It is not enough to change the database *default*.)
- The connection between the client and the server.  See `SET NAMES utf8`.
- The bytes you have.  (This is probably the case.)
- If you are displaying the text in a web page, check the `<meta>` tag.

If you still have troubles after that, come back with `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` for some ill-printing text; this will help in further diagnosing.