# c# mysql AddWithValue unicode

Tags: c#, mysql, unicode

I'm working with C# and MySQL now. I've tried to search around the internet for day to find out why I can't use AddWithValue method to add unicode characters because when I manually add it in MySQL, it works! But back in the C# code with MySQL connector for .NET it doesn't work. Other than the unicode characters is fine.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tb_osm VALUES (@id, @timestamp, @user)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", osmobj.ID);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timestamp", osmobj.TimeStamp);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", osmobj.User);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

For example: osmbj.User = "ສະບາຍດີ", it will be "???????" in the database.
Please T^T

Comment: What is your database charset, do you specify that charset in the connection string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does this link help you?

[read/write unicode data in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385994/read-write-unicode-data-in-mysql)

Basically it says, you should append your connection string with charset=utf8;

Like so:
id=my_user;password=my_password;database=some_db123;charset=utf8;

Comment: Thank you very much this saves me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to be sure that unicode characters are supported at *every level of the process,* all the way from the input into C# to the column stored in MySql.

The C# level is easy, because strings are already utf-16 by default. As long as you're not using some weird gui toolkit, reading from a bad file or network stream, or running in a weird console app environment with no unicode support, you'll be in good shape.

The next layer is the parameter definition. Here, you're [better off avoiding the `AddWithValue()` method](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), anyway. The link pertains the Sql Server, but the same reasoning applies to MySql, even if MySql is less strict with your data than it should be. You should use an `Add()` override that lets you explicitly the declare the type of your parameters as `NVarChar`, instead of making the ADO.Net provider try to guess.

Next up is the connection between your application and the database. Here, you want to [make sure to include the `charset=utf8` clause](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) (or better) as part of the connection string.

Then we need to think about the collation of the database itself. You have to be sure that an `NVarChar` column in MySql will be able to support your data. One of the answers from the question at previous link also covers how to handle this.

Finally, make sure the column is defined with the `NVarChar` type, instead of just `VarChar`.

Comment: yeah, the charset=utf8; is what I want. Thank you for your support :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, utf8 at all stages -- byte-encoding in client, conversion on the wire (charset=utf8), and on the column.  I do not know whether C# converts from utf16 to utf8 before exposing the characters; if it does not, then charset=utf16 (or no setting) may be the correct step.

Because you got multiple `?`, the likely cause is trying to transform non-latin1 characters into a `CHARACTER SET latin1` column.  Since latin1 has no codes for Lao, `?` was substituted.  Probably you said nothing about the column, but depended on the `DEFAULT` on the table and/or database, which happened to be latin1.

The `ສະບາຍດີ` is lost and cannot be recovered from `???????`.

Once you have changed things, check that it is stored correctly by doing `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...`.  For the string `ສະບາຍດີ`, you should get hex `E0BAAAE0BAB0E0BA9AE0BAB2E0BA8DE0BA94E0BAB5`.  Notice how that is groups of `E0BAxx`, which is the range of utf8 values for Lao.

If you still have troubles, please provide the HEX for further analysis.

Comment: thanks for your help and giving me new knowledge, but this charset=utf8; saves me :)