# Not inserting correct characters in SQLyog DB from C#

Tags: c#, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, sqlyog

I have a local DB in SQLyog and `WindowsFormApplication` which is connected to that database. I am from Serbia, so I want to insert and our special characters (š, ć, đ, č, Š, Ć, Đ, Č). I have set DB collation to be UTF-8. But, this seems not to work. When I execute the `INSERT` command in SQL, i get the proper value filled when I execute `SELECT` command and everything works just fine. But, in C# when I try to run insert, some characters are replaced, like č, ć, đ, Ć, Č, with c, c, d, C, C but Đ works as it should.

Example:
When I enter from C# `ćććććććć` I get in `SELECT` clause `cccccccc`.

My code is provided below. I think C# is wrong somewhere here.

C# code:

http://pastebin.com/19u35GsG

The DB is very simple. Just a one column with ID and VAL which is value we insert. This can be easily checked.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# mysql AddWithValue unicode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869645/c-sharp-mysql-addwithvalue-unicode)

Comment: Voting to close.  Short answer:  need something like this in connection string: `id=my_user;password=my_password;database=some_db123;charset=utf8;`

Answer (score -1):

whats the type of column?

look here :

[Reading signs like č ć đ š ž from MySql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057048/reading-signs-like-%C4%8D-%C4%87-%C4%91-%C5%A1-%C5%BE-from-mysql-database?rq=1)