# Character encoding from odbc reader C#

Tags: c#, mysql, character-encoding, odbc

I need to read few columns from MySQL using C# and ODBC. Everything works fine, but characters from my language like ř (don't know others, but I'm sure there will be more). They are showing in the final string as '?'.

This is my code:

```
string sql = "SELECT uzivatelske_jmeno,jmeno,prijmeni FROM zamestnanci WHERE id_user = " + id_user;
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, dbKontrolConn);
OdbcDataReader dbReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dbReader.Read())
{
    uz_jmeno = dbReader["uzivatelske_jmeno"].ToString();
    jmeno = dbReader["jmeno"].ToString();
    prijmeni = dbReader["prijmeni"].ToString();
}
```

Where the string jmeno should be "Jiří" , but it is "Ji?í" instead. Could anyone help me please?

The MySQL database is encoded in utf8_unicode_ci.

Comment: SDee this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385994/read-write-unicode-data-in-mysql

Comment: Thank you, but when I do charset=utf8; it shows as "JiĹ™Ă" -> even worse.

Comment: What is your full connection string?

Comment: This code is likely vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should config mysql session.
Execute SET NAMES command before SELECT -

```
SET NAMES utf8; -- or set encoding you need
```

Or read the docs about MySQL ODBC driver and set it directly in connection string, in this case it will be set by default on connection openning.

Answer (score 0):

`Jiří` in utf8 is hex `4A 69 C599 C3AD`.

`Ji?í` -- The target column's `CHARACTER SET` does not include the intended character (bad).

`JiÅ™Ã` is when you encounter Mojibake.  (Search around here for that.)