# How to input hebrew from winForm to mySql

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, winforms

when I try to insert hebrew on mySql it goes well, but when I am trying to insert hebrew data from winForm input I get "???"

I work with winForm vs 2019 and mySql

```
{
            string query = "INSERT INTO customers (`name`, `adress`, `phone_number`, `cellular`, `Ownership_information`, `Identity`, `email`) VALUES ('" + tbName.Text + "','" + tbAdress.Text + "','" + tbTel.Text + "','" + tbPhone.Text + "','" + tbBalut.Text + "','" + tbPasport.Text + "','" + tbEmail.Text + "')";
            MySqlConnection databaseConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            MySqlCommand commandDatabase = new MySqlCommand(query, databaseConnection);
            commandDatabase.CommandTimeout = 60;

            try
            {
                databaseConnection.Open();
                MySqlDataReader myReader = commandDatabase.ExecuteReader();

                MessageBox.Show("User succesfully registered");

                databaseConnection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Show any error message.
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried including charset in connection string: [read/write unicode data in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1395259)

Comment: Since you have said you can save and view Hebrew text in the mysql table using another tool correctly then you likely have an appropriate encode defined on the table columns. You should try setting the charset in the connection string. That needs to match the encoding you need and the default connection string encoding may not be correct for you. Another problem when viewing the data in your app can be that the Font you are using  doesn't support your characters.

Answer (score 0):

I added Charset=utf8; to my connection string
and now it works well